# What is better for SEO "-" or "()" to describe sub-contents?

Tags: seo, url, keywords

Which of the following sentence is better for SEO `-` or `()`  to describe sub-contents?

```
Ru Ba Ru Feat Diljit - Dj Hans - 48Kbps.mp3
```

URL: `/music/view/25577946?download=Ru-Ba-Ru-Feat-Diljit---Dj-Hans---48Kbps.mp3`

or

```
Ru Ba Ru Feat Diljit (Dj Hans) (48Kbps).mp3
```

URL:`/music/view/25577946?download=Ru-Ba-Ru-Feat-Diljit-(Dj-Hans)-(48Kbps).mp3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use an unfriendly URL, I'd go with:

`/music/view/25577946?download=Ru-Ba-Ru-Feat-Diljit---Dj-Hans---48Kbps.mp3`

However, I'd change it to:

```
/music/view/25577946?download=Ru-Ba-Ru-Feat-Diljit-Dj-Hans-48Kbps.mp3
```

Just to keep things cleaner, I would recommend instead is friendly URLs in this kind of format:

```
/music/artist/song/subcontent
```

For example:

```
/music/Diljit/Ru-Ba-Ru/Dj-Hans
```

Then you can use mod_rewrite Apache module to map the URLs to the actual MP3 files.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^music/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /path/to/downloadprocessor.php?download=$1-$2-$3-48Kbps.mp3
```

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this one more than once.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably negligible if you use Microdata tags around it. The [MusicRecording Schema](https://schema.org/MusicRecording) will allow you to mark up the track name and artist, and [AudioObject](https://schema.org/AudioObject) has a property for bitrate.

Comment: I am asking for general contents. Not audio contents in particular. Also consider it in URL.

Comment: My answer doesn't really change then. Marking up the Microdata of the track would be your better concern. The on-page data will have a far greater effect than the punctuation within a file-download link.